# Use lambda syntax to retrieve a property from an anonymous type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I was trying to do something like this:

```
Dim list = (From c In value
                   Where Not c.IsMatched
                   Select c.City, c.State, c.Country).ToList()

        RadComboBoxSuggestedState.DataSource = list.Select(Function(x) x.city)
```

trying to get the city property from the anonymous type, but I am getting this error:

> System.MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233070
>     Message=Public member 'Select' on type 'List(Of VB$AnonymousType_0(Of String,String,String))' not found.
>     Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic

any help?

Comment: try to follow this [link](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/json-net-s-jobject-to)

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a new anonymous type:

```
Dim list = (From c In value
            Where Not c.IsMatched
            Select New With {.City = c.City, .State = c.State, .Country = c.Country}
```